# Kubernetes doesn't find a jar file

Tags: java, spring, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I'm using this `Dockerfile` configuration

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine

ARG APP_HOME=/app

WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY ./target/ws-exec.jar ws.jar

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Dspring.application.name=words"

ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -jar ./ws.jar $JAVA_ARGS
```

After deploying it to minikube, I see the only log:
`Error: Unable to access jarfile /ws.jar`.

I've tried to run `docker run -it <image>` with my image's name, and it successfuly started with docker. Running `docker exec -it <container>` shew me that the `jar` is present in the right folder. I tried to make the jar executable adding a `CMD` or `RUN` layer into my `Dockerfile`, but nothing helped.
Where is my mistake, or what I don't understand?

UPD here is my deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: revise-words-ws
  name: revise-words-ws
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  minReadySeconds: 45
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: revise-words-ws
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: revise-words-ws
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: maxrybalkin91/revise-words-ws:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: revise-words-ws
          env:
            - name: VAULT_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: words
                  key: vault_token
            - name: VAULT_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: words
                  key: vault_host
            - name: VAULT_PORT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: words
                  key: vault_port
          ports:
            - name: liveness-port
              containerPort: 8089
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 256Mi
            limits:
              cpu: 300m
              memory: 512Mi
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: liveness-port
            failureThreshold: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: liveness-port
            failureThreshold: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Can you `docker run` your image normally?  (As it is constructed, I'd be surprised if `docker run ... bash` gave you an interactive shell.)  If the problem is specifically in Minikube, can you [edit] the question to include your Kubernetes Deployment YAML file?

Comment: @DavidMaze Just added my deployment config.
I had a typo, I didn't use `bash` but used `docker run maxrybalkin91/revise-words-ws:1.0` and saw the app logs in console, which means that the `jar` was found in the image and was executed

Comment: I just tried a `docker run maxrybalkin91/revise-words-ws:1.0`, and it seems the application starts up but complains about missing configuration. Have not tried the environment you specified. But: The title of the question states the jar is not found - and that is not true.
What are we searching here?

Comment: @Queeg it doesn't find the configuration because it's taken from vault, which is run in my minikube

Comment: @Queeg We're searching for a reason why the image is starting in docker, even with an error; but isn't starting in Kubernetes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems a `docker run maxrybalkin91/revise-words-ws:1.0` brings up the application which complains about missing configuration data - but nowhere a jar file that is not found.

Since in minikube you see a completely different error, is it possible you are running some outdated image?

Try changing `imagePullPolilcy=Always` and see what you get.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/

Comment: It helped! Thanks a lot! Seems like it didn't use a new image, even it was rebuilt and pushed to my hub!

Answer (score 4):

As ENTRYPOINT you specify Java to run `./ws.jar`, assuming it would resolve from within work directory `/app`.
At runtime you get the error message that `/ws.jar` is not accessible, which looks like an absolute path.

When running your container with /bin/bash, please check out where your jar file exists and which mode it has. Then decide who is right and who is broken: Your docker file or your error message. Fix the broken one.

Comment: I added `RUN ls ../app/` to my Dockerfile, and here is the build log
```---> Running in fc6abc20b853
ws.jar```

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say the jar file is in the right location (and I assume that is /app), how about using the absolute path for execution?

```
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -jar $APP_HOME/ws.jar $JAVA_ARGS
```

Comment: I've tried that. Didn't help. Interesting thing that running docker image using `docker run` finds the jar and starts the app

Comment: Just tried this `ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -jar ../app/ws.jar  $JAVA_ARGS`, ant it neither helped

Comment: Making `docker run ...` successful is the whole point. If you reached that, what else do you need?

Comment: It doesn't work in kubernetes, my pod fails with the main error

Comment: So what is the 'main error'? Maybe add that to your question. What I perceived is not related to missing jars.